# What's the name of the form $ai+b$ of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

Example: the number $0.5$ can be written as a fraction $\frac {1}{2}$.

Is there an official name for writing a number in the form of $ai + b$?

Complex numbers could also be written in this form $z = a\  e^{i \theta}$. What is that form called?

Comment: I would usually call $a+bi$ the _[rectangular form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)_, and $re^{i\theta}$ the _[polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)_.

Answer (score 4):

I would usually call $a+bi$ the *[rectangular form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)*, and $re^{i\theta}$ the *[polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)*. -- [René B. Christensen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034958/whats-the-name-of-the-form-123i-321#comment2109488_1034958)

Rectangular form is also known as Cartesian form. –- [abel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034958/whats-the-name-of-the-form-aib-of-a-complex-number/1091290?noredirect=1#comment2224157_1091290)

Comment: rectangular form is also known as cartesian form.

Answer (score 2):

*Standard Form*. Source: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ato6/imagineles.htm

(Plus, I think that's what my school calls it.)

Comment: Of course, "rectangular" and "Cartesian" work too, but those terms are usually used when this form is being contrasted to the polar form.